# Publish a WordPress blog at one URL, do administration on another

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, wordpress

Let's say I want to have my blog display at `blog.example.com`, but I own a SSL/TLS cert for `example.com` only.

I want to have authenticated users transparently redirected from `blog.example.com` to `example.com/internal/blog` (which uses TLS) so that their connections can be encrypted. The latter URL should be the admin interface for the blog.

Is this feasible?

I'm using Apache2 on RHEL 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the WordPress' wiki: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: That seems to deal primarilly with a secure and a non-secure host on the same URL. Would I need to make many changes to the instructions to adapt them to different hostnames? 

Also, do you have any thoughts on the plugin it mentions: http://www.kerrins.co.uk/blog/admin-ssl/

Comment: It worked for me a while back, with two different domain.